# What is Evicting cold readers in Cassndra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am running multi node multi DataCenter cluster of Cassandra on which I am frequently getting "Evicting cold readers" which seems to very dangerous for the sstables of Column families.

Due to this message I came across with the issue where Cassandra says FSfile error having unfinished compaction and service gets stopped, Until i removed the complete sstable mentioned in Evicting cold readers message Cassandra is not allowing to start the service again.

Do I ignore and let Cassandra to run as it and remove such file every time or something else is there that I am missing which is why this message is coming so frequently.

Comment: Not sure what's happening there, but the FlieCacheService was removed as a part of 3.0 Alpha, so Cassandra 2.2 is the highest version that could report a `Evicting cold readers` message.  Depending on the actual version, you may be running into a race condition or NPE that's not allowing the files to close properly.  Try upgrading to the latest version of 3.x.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version is challenge in production environment with huge data. In case of any corruption of SStable impact data loss and unavailability.
What would be the best way to come out from this situation?